# MVC 5 using multiple models in one view asynchronous

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to use two models in one view and call them separately (not together)... I have already tried using view models but it didn't work... I have two models student and teacher, I want to access student on page load and teacher while I click on a button...

```
ViewModel mymodel = new ViewModel();
mymodel.Teachers = GetTeachers();
mymodel.Students = GetStudents();
return View(mymodel);// This works

//But if I remove mymodel.Students = GetStudents(); then it gives error
ViewModel mymodel = new ViewModel();
mymodel.Teachers = GetTeachers();
return View(mymodel);
```

How can I do it?

Comment: "it didn't work" isn't good enough in a question. You need to include an example of what you did and an example of the error messages (if any) to indicate what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by sending the student model and the event of the button I created the model teacher and I bring it through an Ajax request.

Comment: yes using ajax is one way to do it.. anything from models is not possible??

Comment: You can create in the controller an object and in this add several objects with the information of the models you need and in the view you receive it with a json.

Comment: will receive this json values using ajax
?